# Should $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z^{3}+1)},z_{0}=0$ be expanded in Taylor series or a Laurent series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

how do I expand the following function

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z^{3}+1)},z_{0}=0$

how do I know if I should expand it in a Taylor series or a Laurent series?

Comment: The function has a pole at $z_0$, so it will have to be a Laurent series, right? In what annulus will your Laurent series converge?

Answer (score 2):

As other people have commented, the given function blows up at $z=0$, so cannot have a power series expansion there.

But, as @user247327 aptly observed, your function is of the form $f(z)={1\over z}\cdot g(z)$ with $g$ holomorphic at $0$, so the Laurent series of $f$ (at $0$) *is* obtained from the Taylor series of $g$ by dividing through by $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Is it infinitely differentiable at $z_0$?  If not, then a Taylor series is hopeless.

The $f$ you give isn't even continuous at $z_0$, so a Laurent series is the only possibility.

Comment: Since $f(z)= \frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{z^3+ 1}$ you can expand $\frac{1}{z^3+ 1}$ in a **Taylor's series** then divide each term by z.

Comment: @user247327 : ... and you will not get a Taylor's series.

Comment: Yes, since f(0) is not 0, the result will not be a Taylor's series.  I didn't say it was!

Comment: @user247327 : If you do not get a Taylor's series, you have not expanded it in Taylor's series, so have failed to respond to OP.  Worse, you appear to be deceiving the OP by emphasizing a Taylor's series while not obtaining one.

Answer (score 0):

Laurent series.  $1/(z(z^3+1))=1/z\sum_{n\ge0}(-z^3)^n=1/z-z^2+z^5-\mathcal O(z^8)$, which converges on the annulus $0\lt z\lt1$.